# How to generate a collage image like shown

Tags: image, photo, photo-gallery

How to generate a collage image like show below. I would appreciate if you can let me know if there are any online tools or apps which do this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image Magick is a free command line tool to process images and they have a feature [called montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php). Go take a look.

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats (over 200) including PNG, JPEG, JPEG-2000, GIF, TIFF, DPX, EXR, WebP, Postscript, PDF, and SVG. Use ImageMagick to resize, flip, mirror, rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.

Comment: Thank you @Bulrush that tool came in handy. I ran a command like this.

Answer (score 15):

Use ImageMagick `montage` like this to get your montage 10 images wide and with all images abutted together with no space between:

```
montage -geometry +0+0 -tile 10x *.jpg result.jpg
```

[image]

My images repeat because I didn't bother finding 1,000 unique faces :-)

Comment: :) the `-tile 10x` will create a 10 by 10 matrix right?

Comment: No, it only sets the number of images across the width. The height will be determined by the number of images you supply.

Comment: If you want to specify the height as, say 5 images, then use `-tile x5` and the width will then depend on the number of images you provide. So, basically, a number **before** the `x` specifies the width and a number **after** the `x` specifies the height.

Comment: When I run this, I get spaces between images? How does your have no spaces between images?

Comment: I made my images all the same size before merging them. You can achieve a similar result by using an exclamation mark after the `-geometry` which will force images to the same size even if it distorts them... `montage -geometry 40x10+0+0! ...`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the above answer of using ImageMagick. I used the below command. Also make sure that ghostscript is installed (available via brew on OS X)

```
montage *.jpg -geometry 40x10+0+0 -tile 18x10 tiled_image.jpg
```

Comment: Ghostscript is not normally required unless you are working with `PDF` files.

Answer (score 0):

The more difficult way to make such image would be by basic photo editing- creating a big white background and copy- pasting the images you like over there but that would take too much time so just google something similar to "collage maker" and you would find lots of tools suitable for any beginner computer user. 
I would suggest downloading one instead of doing it in a browser if privacy matters in your case.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see if there any tools which can help with this instead of the doing it manually.