# I want the pictures to be one big picture connected to the mnemonic in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I want to bind cifar100 picture.
I want to make a final 10 rows and 10 columns of photos.
I want to make an image of a postage stamp, with each picture connected to the other.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar100

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
```

I want to merge the photos to the side or bottom and save them as a large image.
Can I just create a 'for' loop?
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can do that very simply with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37710999/2836621

Comment: Thank you for a very useful tool, it would be nice to be able to complete it with just the python code on colabratory.